# How to include JavaScript and CSS in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, javascript, css

Hi I am creating some web parts in SharePoint 2010 non sandboxed solution. I want to include some JavaScript files and CSS on each page of my site. But I don't want to include my files on each web part or in master page as master page may be changed. Is there any way so that I could dynamically load js/css files which are relevant to a specific page only? Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: You have to include them somewhere... I don't think you can inject them from the server without server side code (non-sandbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give that you are not using a sandboxed solution, you can use a Delegate Control, specifically the AdditionalPageHeadDelegate:

1. You nee to create an ASP.Net Control (ascx file) where you will add the script and css references to the markup
2. Add a feature, and scope it to Web Application
3. Add an empty Elements.xml file to the feature ("Empty element" in the Add.. dialog)
4. Add a the following to your Elements.xml file

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
         <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead" Sequence="90"             
          ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/Microsoft.PFE.DSE.Samples/jQueryControl.ascx" />
    </Elements>
   ```

   ...changing the `ControlrSrc`to match the relativt path to your created ascx file

Complete guide, and loose source of the above: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx

Otherwise, look in the a CustomAction: http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions

Comment: You don't add a webpart to each and every webpart.. you add it as a separate element in a separate feature, and activate it once at the web application level as I write above

Comment: You can also use some cool code behind in the ascx control code to target differents scripts and css to different types of sites and pages etc.